# How to highlight text inside TextFormField widget using regex in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to highlight the text inside the TextFormField when it matches to a regex. Or when I insert a text inside the TextFormField from a dropdown. Like select2 in web. Here is an example:

[image: Example of highlighted text inside an input]

Comment: You can use `Chip`s for that..!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will use the chip to show the selected items from the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already your list it's up to you to add and delete the data inside:

You can do it Like:

```
List<String> _myList = ["USA", "France",];
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            for(var x= 0; x<_myList.length;x++)...{
              Container(
                height: 60,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: (){
                        removeData();
                      }
                    ),
                    Text(_myList[x])
                  ]
                )
              )
            }
          ]
        )
      ),
      Container(
        child: TextFormField(*your code with controller*)
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

assuming that _myList is dynamic list generated from the events you made on your TextFormField Result, this is for UI only